Docker Image for AWS Lambda Succeeds in CodeBuild but Fails to Run Correctly
I'm trying to build a Docker image for an AWS Lambda function which is a PHP API, using a custom Dockerfile. I recently updated the Dockerfile to use Amazon Linux 2 (amazon/aws-lambda-provided:al2) as the base image, but while the CodeBuild succeeds, the resulting Docker image seems to be incompatible with the application code when deployed to AWS Lambda.
Old Dockerfile (Works in Lambda but fails CodeBuild):
The Lambda image that this was using from 2 years ago is working, and the API functionality was undisturbed in the application. But when I merge the code and the codebuild was building I got a failure in build with an error like this.
Status: Downloaded newer image for public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:latest
 ---> xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Step 2/17 : ARG php_version="8.0.16"
 ---> Running in bc5c374a2d1b
Removing intermediate container xxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ---> xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Step 3/17 : RUN yum clean all &&     yum install -y autoconf                 bison                 bzip2-devel                 gcc                 gcc-c++                 git                 gzip                 libcurl-devel                 libxml2-devel                 make                 openssl-devel                 tar                 unzip                 zip                 openldap-devel                 libzip010-compat                 re2c                 sqlite-devel                 oniguruma                 oniguruma-devel                 file                 wget                 libldb-devel
 ---> Running in xxxxxxxxxxxxx
/bin/sh: line 1: yum: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c yum clean all &&     yum install -y autoconf                 bison                 bzip2-devel                 gcc                 gcc-c++                 git                 gzip                 libcurl-devel                 libxml2-devel                 make                 openssl-devel                 tar                 unzip                 zip                 openldap-devel                 libzip010-compat                 re2c                 sqlite-devel                 oniguruma                 oniguruma-devel                 file                 wget                 libldb-devel' returned a non-zero code: 127

[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.114652 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest . exit status 127
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.119545 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.119564 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .. Reason: exit status 127
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.158806 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.159700 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Wed Aug 14 17:29:58 UTC 2024

[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.167271 Running command echo Pushing the Docker images...
Pushing the Docker images...

[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.173839 Running command docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
The push refers to repository [xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-lambda]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-lambda

[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.196466 Command did not exit successfully docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest exit status 1
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.201397 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.201417 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.249533 Set report auto-discover timeout to 5 seconds
[Container] 2024/08/14 17:29:58.249589 Expanding base directory path:  .

Original Docker File:
# Lambda base image Amazon Linux
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided as builder 

# Set desired PHP Version
ARG php_version="8.0.16"

RUN yum clean all && \
    yum install -y autoconf \
                bison \
                bzip2-devel \
                gcc \
                gcc-c++ \
                git \
                gzip \
                libcurl-devel \
                libxml2-devel \
                make \
                openssl-devel \
                tar \
                unzip \
                zip \
                openldap-devel \
                libzip010-compat \
                re2c \
                sqlite-devel \
                oniguruma \
                oniguruma-devel \
                file \
                wget \
                libldb-devel

# Add libsodium needed for PHP 8
RUN wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm && \
    rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm && \
    yum install -y libsodium \
                   libsodium-devel

# Download the PHP source, compile, and install both PHP and Composer
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-${php_version}.tar.gz | tar -xvz && \
    cd php-src-php-${php_version} && \
    ./buildconf --force && \
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-8-bin/ --with-openssl --with-curl --with-zlib --without-pear --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-mbstring --with-libdir=lib64 --with-ldap --with-mysqli && \
    make -j 5 && \
    make install && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php -v && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php -- --install-dir=/opt/php-8-bin/bin/ --filename=composer

# Prepare runtime files
COPY runtime/bootstrap /lambda-php-runtime/
RUN chmod 0755 /lambda-php-runtime/bootstrap

# Install Guzzle, AWS SDK, and prepare vendor files
RUN mkdir /lambda-php-vendor && \
    cd /lambda-php-vendor && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php /opt/php-8-bin/bin/composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php /opt/php-8-bin/bin/composer require aws/aws-sdk-php

# Clean up
RUN yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum

###### Create runtime image ######
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided as runtime

# Layer 1: PHP Binaries
COPY --from=builder /opt/php-8-bin /var/lang

# Layer 2: Runtime Interface Client
COPY --from=builder /lambda-php-runtime /var/runtime

# Layer 3: Vendor
COPY --from=builder /lambda-php-vendor/vendor /opt/vendor

COPY src/ /var/task/

# Install PHP 8 libs
RUN yum install -y oniguruma \
    oniguruma-devel

# Clean up
RUN yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum

CMD [ "index" ]


**
New Dockerfile (Succeeds in CodeBuild but fails in Lambda):**
This Dockerfile Succeeded in the Codebuild and performed without any errors, but when I deploy the image created by this build in the Lambda it is disrupting the API functionality that my application requires. Here's the Codebuild log where I think there might be an issue.
Successful Codebuild log where issue might be stemming from.
Codebuild status:
# Lambda base image Amazon Linux 2
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-provided:al2 as builder

# Set desired PHP Version
ARG php_version="8.0.16"

RUN yum clean all && \
    yum install -y autoconf \
                bison \
                bzip2-devel \
                gcc \
                gcc-c++ \
                git \
                gzip \
                libcurl-devel \
                libxml2-devel \
                make \
                openssl-devel \
                tar \
                unzip \
                zip \
                openldap-devel \
                libzip010-compat \
                re2c \
                sqlite-devel \
                oniguruma \
                oniguruma-devel \
                file \
                wget \
                libldb-devel \
                libsodium \
                libsodium-devel

# Download the PHP source, compile, and install both PHP and Composer
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-${php_version}.tar.gz | tar -xvz && \
    cd php-src-php-${php_version} && \
    ./buildconf --force && \
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-8-bin/ --with-openssl --with-curl --with-zlib --without-pear --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-mbstring --with-libdir=lib64 --with-ldap --with-mysqli && \
    make -j 5 && \
    make install && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php -v && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php -- --install-dir=/opt/php-8-bin/bin/ --filename=composer

# Prepare runtime files
COPY runtime/bootstrap /lambda-php-runtime/
RUN chmod 0755 /lambda-php-runtime/bootstrap

# Install Guzzle, AWS SDK, and prepare vendor files
RUN mkdir /lambda-php-vendor && \
    cd /lambda-php-vendor && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php /opt/php-8-bin/bin/composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle && \
    /opt/php-8-bin/bin/php /opt/php-8-bin/bin/composer require aws/aws-sdk-php

# Clean up
RUN yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum

###### Create runtime image ######
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided as runtime

# Layer 1: PHP Binaries
COPY --from=builder /opt/php-8-bin /var/lang

# Layer 2: Runtime Interface Client
COPY --from=builder /lambda-php-runtime /var/runtime

# Layer 3: Vendor
COPY --from=builder /lambda-php-vendor/vendor /opt/vendor

COPY src/ /var/task/

CMD [ "index" ]


Question
How can I resolve the compatibility issue with my new Docker image so that it runs correctly on AWS Lambda? Are there any known issues or differences with Amazon Linux 2 that I should account for when building the image?
Any guidance on identifying the specific incompatibilities or suggestions for modifying my Dockerfile would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to AWS and Docker so it's a steep learning for me, please be descriptive if y'all have a solution Jr. Dev here!! :')
Verified that all dependencies required for PHP 8.0.16 are installed.
Checked that the bootstrap file and other runtime files have the correct permissions.
Made sure that all necessary PHP extensions are compiled and installed.
Ensured that the Lambda function handler matches the CMD specified in the Dockerfile.

You need to edit your question to explain what you mean by "succeeds" and "fails" in both CodeBuild and AWS Lambda. After reading your question, I have no idea what errors or unexpected behavior you are encountering in either environment, so I don't see how anyone would be able to help you. Please provide all error messages, as well as clear descriptions of any unexpected behavior, in the question itself.

Sorry, will do that BRB...

"it is disrupting the API functionality" is not a clear description of an error or unexpected behavior. Again, I ask you to please provide all relevant information necessary to understand the problem. You should be including error logs from the Lambda function that doesn't perform correctly, or describing in detail what doesn't work exactly.

yum: command not found - this problem does not look related to PHP itself

i think the issue is with the base image which you are using. Use a base image which contains yum package

Sorry about not providing sufficient detail in the Question, logs were 20k-ish lines. I think I found the solution but it is not perfect yet.

While installing the EPEL release package for RHEL 7 there was the issue.
This link is no longer supported and could not be found:
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
By updating the link to look for the package in the Fedora's archives, it now works:
RUN yum -y install https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-14.noarch.rpm
